# Solr: I have set `hl=true` but no summaries are being output

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine, information-retrieval, nutch

I need to get snippets from documents where the query terms are matched to be able to output results similar to Google's snippet beneath the website URL. For example:

> Snippet - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
>   en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snippet
>   A snippet is defined as a small piece of something, it may in more  specific contexts refer to: Sampling (music), the use of a short phrase  of a recording as an ...

I have set `hl=true` and even `hl.fl='*'` in the query URL and but no summaries are being output.

[Solr FAQs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#I_have_set_.60hl.3Dtrue.60_but_no_summaries_are_being_output) say:

> For a field to be summarizable it must be both stored and indexed.

I'm using Nutch and Solr and have set them up using [this tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#A4._Setup_Solr_for_search). What additional steps to I need to take to be able to do this?

---

Adding sample query and output:

> http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=test&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&hl=true

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">57</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="indent">on</str>
<str name="start">0</str>
<str name="q">test</str>
<str name="hl">true</str>
<str name="version">2.2</str>
<str name="rows">10</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="94" start="0">
<doc>
<arr name="anchor">
<str>User:Sir Lestaty de Lioncourt</str>
</arr>
<float name="boost">0.0</float>
<str name="digest">6c27160d0b08068f3873bb2c063508b3</str>
<str name="id">
http://aa.wikibooks.org/wiki/User:Sir_Lestaty_de_Lioncourt
</str>
<str name="segment">20111029223245</str>
<str name="title">User:Sir Lestaty de Lioncourt - Wikibooks</str>
<date name="tstamp">2011-10-29T21:34:27.055Z</date>
<str name="url">
http://aa.wikibooks.org/wiki/User:Sir_Lestaty_de_Lioncourt
</str>
</doc>
...
</result>
<lst name="highlighting">
<lst name="http://aa.wikibooks.org/wiki/User:Sir_Lestaty_de_Lioncourt"/>
<lst name="http://aa.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:PipepBot"/>
<lst name="http://aa.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Purodha"/>
...
</lst>
</response>
```

Comment: whats the query you are using ? summaries would be generated only when queried i.e. q=something

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you aren't specifying the field to highlight (hl.fl). You should create a text field to use for highlighting (don't use string type) and have it stored/indexed.